# Easy-to-update parallelizable hashes

Tags: hash, parallelization

Do any parallelizable cryptographic hash algorithms that allow for quick—preferably constant-time—recalculation of a hash result upon updating a portion of the data input exist?

I know that BLAKE3 is called "parallelizable", but a Merkle tree doesn't seem like it's what I'm looking for when the time taken to recalculate the final result changes according the input's size. I figured something like an unkeyed XOR MAC would suffice until I read [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16506/21260).

Comment: Merkle trees are the obvious solution. They're updated in log(total_length) time. A logarithm is close enough to constant in practice. Why doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: Here is [an earlier question of mine](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/counter-mode-secure-hash-algorithm). Unfortunately there seem to be main theoretical issues with combining input blocks using an algorithm with high performance. My main issue was that Merkle trees may have relatively large overhead. I guess you can tweak the data size that hashed in such a way that the time to hash, while keeping the tree itself relatively small as well.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It would require to store the hash tree if you only want to update part of the input message. Otherwise you'd have to recalculate the entire tree.